# VBA use InputBox to define name of sheet and store it in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for hours now and no solution, I am trying to define a variable from InputBox, to use it as Sheet name and copy value from range A1.

the sheet name should be the one from Inputbox..

```
Dim wss As String
wss = InputBox("Sheet name")
Sheets("EBS Posting template").Range("A1") = Wss.Range("A1")
```

This isn't working either

```
Sheets("EBS Posting template").Range("A1") = Sheets(Wss).Range("A1")
```

Comment: `Sheets(Wss).Range("A1")` should work assuming there's a sheet named `wss` in the ActiveWorkbook.   `Wss.Range("A1")` doesn't work because `wss` is a String variable and not a worksheet object

Comment: Run-time error '9'

Comment: That's telling you one of those sheet names is mis-spelled.  Are all sheets in the same workbook?

Comment: and how could I define the sheet name from inputbox? and store it in a variable

Comment: It should work as you have it in the second example.

Comment: It is working with wss = "sheet1" but not with wss = inputbox("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me. I think the issue is that you missed the **value** at the range:

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim wss As String
wss = InputBox("Sheet name")
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets(wss).Range("b1")

End Sub
```